Google Web Risk and appropriate URLs
The Safe Browsing documentation was updated late last year to include a section about appropriate URLs, mentioning that "Google Safe Browsing is designed to act on URLs that would be displayed in a browser's address bar".
The Web Risk documentation doesn't contain any similar information. As the commercial alternative to Google Safe Browsing, the question is if has been designed with the same thoughts in mind and if the same rule should be followed when being used for the same purpose? It seems reasonable that the SOCIAL_ENGINEERING only should be checked towards the main frame, does the same apply for all threat types?

The commercial alternative to Google Safe Browsing, the Web Risk API, is designed to provide similar protection against various online threats, including social engineering attacks. Attaching here the documentation for Web Risk API that mentioned:

client applications check URLs against Google's constantly updated lists of unsafe web resources. Examples of unsafe web resources are social engineering sites, like phishing and deceptive sites, and sites that host malware or unwanted software.

